# Filter data in ruby on rails by subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 tables `news` and `news_type`. Also I have 3 base types for news: politic, technology and sport. How I can filter this data by subdomain?

For example:

If I go to `example.com` I get all news in my home page

If I go to `sport.example.com` I get all news with type `sport`

And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb file, you can provide constraints on the path.  For example:

```
# routes.rb
...
get "/" => "sports#index",  constraints: { domain: "sport.example.com" }
get "/" => "tech#index",  constraints: { domain: "tech.example.com" }
root :to => 'static#index'
```

This would route

- `sport.example.com` to the `index` action within `SportsController`
- `tech.example.com` to the `index` action within `TechsController`
- `example.com` to the `index` action within `StaticController`

Comment: Thanks, it's help!
But I add all page logic in 1 controller
I do something like this

`get "/" => "home#index",  constraints: { domain: "sport.example.com" }, :filter => 'sport'` and 
`get "/" => "home#index",  constraints: { domain: "tech.example.com" }, :filter => 'tech'`

Comment: Perfect, that's even simpler if your controller definitions are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tyler for the answer, however I came across a constraint method which allows a more dynamic solution for subdomains for lets say the tags that are assigned to a news_item i.e: "rugby.example.com" would fetch all news_items with the rugy tag attached.

```
  # routes
  constraints(Subdomain) do
    match "/" => "news_items#index"
  end

  #lib/subdomain.rb
  class Subdomain
    def self.matches?(request)
      request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
    end
  end

  # news_items_controller.rb
  def index
    @item_tag = ItemTag.find_by_title(request.subdomain)
    @news_items = @item_tag ? @item_tag.news_items : NewsItem.all
  end
```

important to note is that this needs to be declared above your traditional root declaration.